# How to see diff from HEAD for unmerged files, only?

Tags: git

After fixing a merge conflict, I want to see the actual diff of my unmerged files **before** adding them to resolve the conflict.

I can see the diff of every files with `git diff HEAD`, but this also show me the diffs of non-conflicting files.

I can see unmerged files with `git diff`, but this show me the conflict and not the actual diff.

How can I see the diff between `HEAD` and the actual files content, for conflicting files only?

---

Here is how to create a repro (in an empty directory):

```sh
git init
# Create files foo.txt and bar.txt on master.
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"
echo 'foo content' > foo.txt
echo 'bar content' > bar.txt
git add .
git commit -m A
# Create a branch "b" that change both files.
git checkout -b b
echo 'Foo content' > foo.txt
echo 'Bar content' > bar.txt
git add .
git commit -m B
# Get back on master and add a commit that change foo.txt.
git checkout -
echo 'foo content and more' > foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m C
# Try to merge b in master: CONFLICT!
git merge b
# Fix the conflict.
echo 'Foo content and more' > foo.txt
```

Now, `git diff HEAD` gives me a list of all changes, including `bar.txt` which is not conflicting:

```
diff --git a/bar.txt b/bar.txt
index 085e7f5..6401b08 100644
--- a/bar.txt
+++ b/bar.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-bar content
+Bar content
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 6633fd8..a65c68b 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo content and more
+Foo content and more
```

On the other hand, `git diff` gives me only conflicting files, but it doesn't show me the actual diff between the actual content on disk and `HEAD`.

```
diff --cc foo.txt
index 6633fd8,6fc4556..0000000
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- foo content and more
 -Foo content
++Foo content and more
```

I'd like a command with the same output as `git diff HEAD -- foo.txt`, but without specifying the conflicting files.

`git diff --magic-flag HEAD`:

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 6633fd8..a65c68b 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo content and more
+Foo content and more
```

Comment: Try `git diff HEAD -- $(git status -s | grep ^UU | awk '{print $NF}')`. But I think there are better solutions.

Comment: I experience the same pain and mostly use the same method as @ElpieKay here, except that generally, I just look at one specific file that I think I have resolved, so, the explicit `git diff HEAD -- foo.txt` that you don't like doing. It would be useful to have a little script that extracts the `UU` files.

Answer (score 0):

This command seems to do the job:

```
git diff HEAD -- $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)
```

I aliased it as `git dhu` (**d**iff **h**ead **u**nmerged), in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
dhu = !git diff HEAD -- $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)
```